# Django-rest-framework: Browsable API can't get POST data via HTML form, but can from Raw data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Well, the problem is simple. If I post my data via the HTML form, a new record is created in the DB but all data passed is null, as shown in the picture.

[post response via html form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7j1T8.png)

However, if a use the "raw_data" interface, everything works just fine:

[post response via raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHwXB.png)

Code is quite simple:

views.py:

```
class CollectionList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Collection.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CollectionSerializer
```

serializer.py:

```
class CollectionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Collection
    fields = ('id','title', 'nlikes')
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to upgrade django rest framework to 3.3.1. There was a bug in 3.3.0 that sets all form data to empty values when using the session login.

Edit:
The issue was https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/3574